# How to draw a Frenet Trihedron in Sage?

Tags: sagemath

How would I draw this in sage? It's a Frenet Trihedron along a given curve:

[image]

Tools other then Sage are welcome too.

Im just interested in which equations I need to input, besides the curve to obtain the animation.

Comment: There are [various official places](http://www.sagemath.org/development.html#mailingList) to get Sage help, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't yet know *Sage* well enough to carry this off, but here's some *Mathematica* code:

```
fn[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t], t/2}
fnD1[t_] := Simplify[D[fn[tt], tt] /. tt -> t, Trig -> True]
fnD1n[t_] := Simplify[fnD1[t]/Sqrt[fnD1[t].fnD1[t]], Trig -> True]
fnD2[t_] := Simplify[D[fnD1n[tt], tt] /. tt -> t, Trig -> True]
fnD2n[t_] := Simplify[fnD2[t]/Sqrt[fnD2[t].fnD2[t]], Trig -> True]
binormal[t_] := Simplify[Cross[fnD1n[t], fnD2n[t]], Trig -> True]
trihedron[t_] := {fn[t], fnD1n[t], fnD2n[t], binormal[t]}

curve = ParametricPlot3D[fn[t], {t, 0, 10}];
Animate[
 tri = trihedron[t];
 Show[{curve, 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Line[{tri[[1]], tri[[1]] + tri[[2]]}], Green, 
 Line[{tri[[1]], tri[[1]] + tri[[3]]}], Blue, 
 Line[{tri[[1]], tri[[1]] + tri[[4]]}]}]}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

The expression D[f[x],x] computes the derivative of f; Cross computes the cross product; Trig->True instructs *Mathematica* to simplify trig expressions.  You will probably want to hard-code the formulas for fnD1n, fnD2n, and binormal.  They are simple enough:

```
fnD1n[t] = {-Sin[t], Cos[t], 1/2} * (2/Sqrt[5])
fnD2n[t] = {-Cos[t], -Sin[t], 0}
binormal[t] = {Sin[t], -Cos[t], 2} * (1/Sqrt[5])
```

**Addendum:** As I said, I'm no expert in *Sage*.  I actually didn't think the code above was all that long, but it could have been shortened a bit by hard-coding the formulas for the three unit vectors rather than computing them from the definitions.  The latter has the advantage of allowing the code to be easily adapted for other curves.

Here's some code to draw a still image in *Sage*:

```
t=var('t');
pl1=parametric_plot3d( (cos(t), sin(t), t/2), (t, 0, 10));
a=9;
pl2=parametric_plot3d( (cos(a) - t*sin(a)*2/sqrt(5), sin(a)+t*cos(a)*2/sqrt(5), 
 a/2+t*1/2*2/sqrt(5)), (t,0,1), texture="red");
pl3=parametric_plot3d( (cos(a) - t*cos(a), sin(a)-t*sin(a)*2/sqrt(5), a/2+t*0), 
 (t,0,1), texture="green");
pl4=parametric_plot3d( (cos(a) + t*sin(a)*1/sqrt(5), sin(a)-t*cos(a)*1/sqrt(5), 
 a/2+t*2*1/sqrt(5)), (t,0,1), texture="blue");
pl1+pl2+pl3+pl4
```

You'll see that the unit vectors have been hard-coded in this version.  The trihedron is moved along the curve by varying $a$.  I haven't figured out how to animate this yet.  I have seen examples in the *Sage* documentation where a 2-D plot is animated, but not 3-D.  Apparently there's some work to be done in this area.  See the following posts:

http://ask.sagemath.org/question/99/animate-3d-plots

http://ask.sagemath.org/question/1422/3d-animation-with-tachyon

http://freeblogin.blogspot.com/2011/09/sage-devel-animating-3d-plots.html

Comment: Could you convert this to Sage? I'll accept your answer then. Expected it to have less code.

Comment: Why would you expect it to have less code? The Mathmatica code that Will gave is pretty much minimal!